# How to add logs before WebDriverWait gets time-out

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selendroid

I use selendroid in order to test an hybrid application. I have my own logger which logs and also use WebDriverWait to wait for specific behavior. My question is how can I use my logger before WebDriverWait is failed and throws timeoutException?

Answer (score 1):

First, I know nothing about selendroid.

A simple solution could be:

```
public void waitForCondition(WebElement element){
    try{
        new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element)); // your condition
    } catch (TimeoutException e){
        // do log or whatever
    }
}
```

Anyway, You usually do this by implementing [WebDriverEventListener](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html) and register this with [EventFiringWebDriver](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html), then invoke it something like:

```
EventFiringWebDriver eventFiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver());
MyWebDriverEventListener listener = new MyWebDriverEventListener();
eventFiringWebDriver.register(listener);
```

where `MyWebDriverEventListener` is something like

```
class MyWebDriverEventListener implements WebDriverEventListener {
            // .. skipped
}
```

So, basically what `WebDriverWait`'s `until` method is doing, is that it is executing the `driver.findElement` until:

Repeatedly applies this instance's input value to the given function until one of the following occurs:

- the function returns neither null nor false,
- the function throws an unignored exception,
- the timeout expires,
- the current thread is interrupted

So what you could do, is implement your logging in `WebDriverEventListener`

```
public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    // Do logging 
}
```

This would be applyed every time element is found (not only wait, but regular driver.findElement also). Anyway, this does not cover the case when exception is thrown. You also have a chance to log in `onException` method, using something like

```
if (throwable instanceof TimeoutException){
    // log
}
```

I would not do it but it's your code.

That being said, I usually don't do this because I do not care about such verbose log level, I just have 2 helper methods that can take care of all the waits I ever need:

```
public void waitUntil(WebElement element) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
}

public void waitUntil(List<WebElement> elements) {
    new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
            .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
            .ignoring(StaleElementReferenceException.class)
            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElements(elements));
}
```

It would be trivial to add logging there.

---

Edit: i have following solution working:

```
public class Demo {

    @Test
    public void testEventFire(){
        EventFiringWebDriver firingWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(new FirefoxDriver());
        firingWebDriver.register(new MyListener());
        try {
            firingWebDriver.navigate().to(new URL("http://www.google.com"));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static class MyListener extends AbstractWebDriverEventListener {
        @Override
        public void beforeNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) {
            System.out.println("beforeNavigateTo");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I tried the solution using EventFiringWebDriver using the following code: driver = new SelendroidDriver(caps); EventFiringWebDriver eventFiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(driver); eventFiringWebDriver.register(new MyWebDriverEventListener());

where MyWebDriverEventListener is listener as in your answer.
Actually I don't see any logs, do you know what can be the problem?

Comment: Actually not. I put System.out.println in every callback and it looks like the code don't reach any of them

Comment: check my edit. If it is not working, it might be an issue with selendroid.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Message property of WebDriverWait which you may set your failure message.

It is a good idea to wrap a Wait function in a static class like this (you may avoid creating the WebDriverWait object all the time) and set the Message:

```
private static IWebDriver activeDriver;
private static WebDriverWait activeWait;
public static WebDriverWait Wait(this IWebDriver driver, string message = "Test has timed out while finding a UI element")
{
    if (driver != activeDriver)
    {
        activeDriver = driver;
        try
        {
            activeWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw Exception(message);
        }
    }
    activeWait.Message = message;

    return activeWait;
}
```

To call the Wait wrapper above (since it is written as an extension method):

```
YourDriverObject.Wait("Your failure message").Until(ExpectedConditions);
```

If you want the simplest form (without wrapping etc.):

```
var webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeout);
webDriverWait.Message = "Your message when exception is thrown";
```